# Combining a vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl

I've been reading [Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) and I have to say it's an interesting book.

In chapter 6, I have to use a function from <algorithm> to concatenate from a vector<string> into a single string.  I could use accumulate, but it doesn't help because string containers can only push_back characters.

```
int main () {
  using namespace std;
  string str = "Hello, world!";
  vector<string>  vec (10, str);
  // Concatenate here?

  return 0;
}
```

How do I join the strings together?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted solution to something less inefficient.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Assuming this is question 6.8, it doesn't say you have to use accumulate - it says use "a library algorithm". However, you can use accumulate:

```
#include <numeric>
    
int main () {
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    std::vector<std::string> vec(10,str);
    std::string a = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::string(""));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

All that accumulate does is set 'sum' to the third parameter, and then for all of the values 'val' from first parameter to second parameter, do:

```
sum = sum + val
```

it then returns 'sum'. Despite the fact that accumulate is declared in `<numeric>` it will work for anything that implements `operator+()`

---

**Note**: *This solution, while elegant, is inefficient, as a new string will be allocated and populated for each element of `vec`.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried using accumulate with the 3rd parameter as a.begin, didn't work, also I tried with back_inserter which failed too. Can you explain how this works? Thanks alot.

Comment: It takes each element in the vector from .begin() to .end() and accumulates them in to the third parameter, which is an empty std::string passed in as a temporary.  std::acumulate()'s return value is the result of the accumulation, passed by value.

Comment: Btw, this approach possibly scales very badly since there might be a lof of copying / reallicating involved.

Comment: `std::reduce` (C++17) - more faster than `std::accumulate`: 
`std::string a = std::reduce(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::string(""));`

Answer (score 18):

How about std::copy?

```
std::ostringstream os;
std::copy( vec_strings.begin(), vec_string.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( os ) );
std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Can you compare this solution to the accepted one?

Comment: accepted answer is O(N^2): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347123/how-to-construct-a-stdstring-from-a-stdvectorstring

Answer (score 12):

The following snippet compiles in Visual C++ 2012 and uses a lambda function:

```
int main () {
    string str = "Hello World!";
    vector<string>  vec (10,str);

    stringstream ss;
    for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&ss] (const string& s) { cat(ss, s); });

    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

The `accumulate` example in the 1st answer is elegant, but as [sellibitze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172531/sellibitze) pointed out, it reallocates with each concatenation and scales at O(N²). This `for_each` snippet scales at about O(N). I profiled both solutions with 100K strings; the `accumulate` example took 23.6 secs, but this `for_each` snippet took 0.054 sec.

Comment: It could be even faster to create an `std::sring` call `reserve(final-size)`, then just use `+=` which should be fast since the buffer is already of the right size.

Comment: @pixelgrease, what is the cat function? how is it defined? thanks

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure about your question.Where lies the problem? Its just a matter of a loop.

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

int main () 
{
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    std::vector<string>  vec (10,str);

    for(size_t i=0;i!=vec.size();++i)
        str=str+vec[i];
    std::cout<<str;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Use `for_each()` from `<algorithm>`

Try this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
string i;
void func(string &k)
{
  i+=k;
}
int main () {
    string str = "Hello World!";
    vector<string>  vec (10,str);

    for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),func);
    cout<<i;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I have to use a function from algorithm header to do this.

Comment: Or use a proper functor With for_each instead of a free function. Saves you having a global variable

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an improved version of the one from @PrasoonSaurav by adding a helpful `sep` argument.

```
inline std::string joinStrings(std::vector<std::string> arr, std::string sep) {
    std::string out = arr[0];
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        out += sep + arr[i];
    }
    return out;
}

// Overload function parameter to add default value for the separator
inline std::string joinStrings(std::vector<std::string> arr) {
    return joinStrings(arr, std::string(", "));
}
```