# How to construct a std::string from a std::vector<string>?

Tags: c++, stl, string-concatenation, stringstream, stdstring

I'd like to build a `std::string` from a `std::vector<std::string>`.

I could use `std::stringsteam`, but imagine there is a shorter way:

```
std::string string_from_vector(const std::vector<std::string> &pieces) {
  std::stringstream ss;

  for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator itr = pieces.begin();
      itr != pieces.end();
      ++itr) {
    ss << *itr;
  }

  return ss.str();
}
```

How else might I do this?

Comment: Perhaps `std::string res; for (...) { res += *it; }`?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

## C++03

```cpp
std::string s;
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
    s += *i;
return s;
```

## C++11 *(the MSVC 2010 subset)*

```cpp
std::string s;
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const std::string &piece){ s += piece; });
return s;
```

## C++11

```cpp
std::string s;
for (const auto &piece : v) s += piece;
return s;
```

**Don't use `std::accumulate` for string concatenation**, it is a classic [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm), even worse than the usual example using `strcat` in C. Without C++11 move semantics, it incurs two unnecessary copies of the accumulator for each element of the vector. Even with move semantics, it still incurs one unnecessary copy of the accumulator for each element.

The three examples above are **O(n)**.

`std::accumulate` is **O(n²)** for strings.

> You could make `std::accumulate` O(n) for strings by supplying a
> custom functor:
>
> ```
> std::string s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string{},
>     [](std::string &s, const std::string &piece) -> decltype(auto) { return s += piece; });
> ```
>
> Note that `s` must be a reference to non-const, the lambda return type
> must be a reference (hence `decltype(auto)`), and the body must use
> `+=` not `+`.

## C++20

In the current draft of what is expected to become C++20, the definition of `std::accumulate` has been [altered](http://wg21.link/p0616r0) to use `std::move` when appending to the accumulator, so from C++20 onwards, `accumulate` will be **O(n)** for strings, and can be used as a one-liner:

```
std::string s = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string{});
```

Comment: I like the FP way, but it's a bit weird looking at the moment. Really looking forward to c++20 to clear things up!

Comment: How do you come up with the idea that calling `operator+=` would result in linear growth? Unless you reserve the capacity `string` might need to relocate the content for every single append-operation. That is the same for `+=`, `append` and `accumulate` - they all can be **O(n²)**

Comment: @ABaumstumpf Appending a single character is amortized O(1) in all major implementations. They grow the capacity by an exponential growth factor, so that the frequency of reallocation shrinks as the string grows. So after appending many characters, the total number of characters copied due to reallocation is proportional to the number of characters appended. `accumulate` being O(n²) would be a very pathological worst case, with O(n) being the average case. Summing the sizes to call `reserve` could be an optimization or a pessimization depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @Oktalist "in all major implementations."
But it is not guaranteed by the standard so your claimed O(n) can very well be O(n²). On the other hand with `reserve` you would guarantee it to be O(n)

Comment: Is it confirmed C++20 std::accumulate uses std::move ?

Comment: @kwaalaateimaa Yes: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/accumulate#2

Answer (score 40):

You could use the [`std::accumulate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) standard function from the `<numeric>` header (it works because an overload of `operator +` is defined for `string`s which returns the concatenation of its two arguments):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello, ", " Cruel ", "World!"};
    std::string s;
    s = accumulate(begin(v), end(v), s);
    std::cout << s; // Will print "Hello, Cruel World!"
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a more efficient, small `for` cycle:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello, ", "Cruel ", "World!"};
    std::string result;
    for (auto const& s : v) { result += s; }
    std::cout << result; // Will print "Hello, Cruel World!"
}
```

Comment: Cute, but careless.  It's going to allocate a new string for every single operation, because it uses `operator+` and generates a new string, instead of `operator+=` to modify an existing one.

Comment: I've written a library using which it would be just `s = v | sum();` that internally uses `+=` instead of `+` ;-)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley actually not for every since most implementations just twice capability each realloc

Comment: +1 for using free begin() end() instead of .begin .end member functions.

Comment: @PSIAlt: Huh? Is that sentence missing some words?  Because I don't understand it.

Comment: @PSIAlt: Read it again,  it allocates a new string for every operation because every operations _generates a new string_.  The doubling-size-optimization doesn't affect this.  BenjaminLindley: he's talking about how string "doubles" it's capacity when you put too much in it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley actually if your dataset is very big, you may first want to iterate a first time and accumulate all the string sizes, `reserve()` the target string a single time and *then* iterate again using `operator +=`. This can avoid a lot of useless reallocations.

Comment: @syam but this introduces useless vector iteration

Comment: @PSIAlt which is why I mentioned that it depends on your dataset. Given enough (long) strings in the vector, the cost for iterating twice (with allows us to have a single memory allocation) will be much lower than iterating only once and reallocating the memory several times. How useless and costly do you think it is to copy the same data over and over into larger and larger buffers? ;)

Comment: Using GNU C++ 2011 v5.3.1, I got an error using said example:

'    In function 'int main()'
    error: 's' was not declared in this scope
    std::cout << s; // Will print "Hello, Cruel World!"'

Comment: its **result += s + " "** if your vector doesn't have spaces between elements.

Answer (score 13):

My personal choice would be the range-based for loop, as in [Oktalist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703743/341970).

Boost also offers a nice solution:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<std::string> v{"first", "second"};

    std::string joined = boost::algorithm::join(v, ", ");

    std::cout << joined << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

> first, second

Answer (score 8):

Why not just use operator + to add them together?

```
std::string string_from_vector(const std::vector<std::string> &pieces) {
   return std::accumulate(pieces.begin(), pieces.end(), std::string(""));
}
```

std::accumulate uses std::plus under the hood by default, and adding two strings is concatenation in C++, as the operator + is overloaded for std::string.

Comment: I would name the function as `to_string` instead of `string_from_vector`.

Comment: I probably would too, but that's the name that was used in the original question.

Answer (score 5):

Google Abseil has function absl::StrJoin that does what you need.

Example from their [header](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/04edad3801ec0b1091df9157b879d8f6a50c5036/absl/strings/str_join.h#L40) file. 
Notice that separator can be also `""`

```
//   std::vector<std::string> v = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
//   std::string s = absl::StrJoin(v, "-");
//   EXPECT_EQ("foo-bar-baz", s);
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but I liked the fact that we can use initializer lists:

```
std::string join(std::initializer_list<std::string> i)
{
  std::vector<std::string> v(i);
  std::string res;
  for (const auto &s: v) res += s;
  return res;   
}
```

Then you can simply invoke (Python style):

```
join({"Hello", "World", "1"})
```

Comment: Why are you taking a `std::initializer_list` instead of a `std::vector`? Also, I don't think you need to make a copy of the vector so could pass by const reference.

Comment: @jb both initlist or vectors are wrong. what functions working with collections should take in are ranges. by application of duck typing principle, minimum requirement principle and decoupling principle.

Comment: @v.oddou what do you mean by "ranges" in this context?

Comment: @v.oddou that looks very cool, but in the context of this answer I think it's unfair to say a `const std:vector<std::string>&` is "wrong" when using `range` introduces a substantial third party dependency to solve the problem. If it is accepted into the standard library, then it becomes a different matter.

Comment: @jb yes I'm thinking ahead of current standardization status. but there was an unsaid supplementary reason why I allowed myself this leap of faith, it's that you can replace "range" mentally with the next best thing we have right now and that is "two iterators". Squint your eyes to believe they are a range until it's true in c++20. Under this hypothesis it's still reasonable to say that `init_list` and `vector` are both wrong. It needs to be a template on some iterator type and take in begin and end.

Comment: @v.oddou that's an interesting approach I hadn't considered before. I always find myself wishing C++ had Python's iterables, the "two iterators" approach is kind of a way of achieving a similar pattern

Comment: @jb yes, and this is the choice made by the library standard committee. You will find that all functions here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm conform to the "two iterators" pattern. And probably will be ported to range in C++20.

Comment: @jb I just finished writing an article that talks about that :) If you want to take a quick glance at it https://motsd1inge.wordpress.com/2019/03/22/principle-of-maximum-opportunity/

Answer (score 3):

If requires no trailing spaces, use `accumulate` defined in `<numeric>` with custom join lambda.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    string s;

    v.push_back(string("fee"));
    v.push_back(string("fi"));
    v.push_back(string("foe"));
    v.push_back(string("fum"));

    s = accumulate(begin(v), end(v), string(),
                   [](string lhs, const string &rhs) { return lhs.empty() ? rhs : lhs + ' ' + rhs; }
    );
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
fee fi foe fum
```

Answer (score 1):

With c++11 the **stringstream** way is not too scary:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v{"Hello, ", " Cruel ", "World!"};
   std::stringstream s;
   std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), [&s](const std::string &elem) { s << elem; } );
   std::cout << s.str();
}
```

Comment: Why not use `for (auto &i: v) { s << i; }` instead of the for_each line?

Comment: Why even use a stringstream at all? Make `s` a string, and make the lambda `{ s += elem }`

Comment: @Oktalist no! it's the schoolbook example of Schlemiel the painter pessimization. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @v.oddou It's not a Schlemiel the painter, as `std::string` knows its own length. It doesn't have to iterate over `s` to find the null terminator. It could be improved, though, by using `std::string::reserve` to avoid repeated allocations for `s`. See also my top-voted (but not accepted) answer above.

Comment: @Oktalist I also upvoted your answer, it's great. But "knows its own size" doesn't appear to be guaranteed https://stackoverflow.com/a/256309/893406

Comment: @Oktalist ok apparently it IS guaranteed when considering end()-begin() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256033/is-stdstring-size-a-o1-operation/256309#comment18367004_256309 so don't mind my blabber.