# Effective using std::accumulate with std::string

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

I'm fan STL algorithms, so I frequently use many STL algorithms in my job. But,...

Consider following simple example:
  // Compiler: Visual Studio 2010 Sp1. Cpu: i5 3300MG.

```
struct FileInfo
{
   std::string filename_;
   std::string filename()const { return filename_;}
};

//works with 1000 FileInfos,  Elapsed: 127.947 microseconds
std::string sumof_filenames_1(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
   std::string s;
   for( std::size_t ix = 0u; ix < fv.size(); ++ix) s += fv[ix].filename();
   return s;
}

//Elapsed: 7430.138 microseconds
std::string sumof_filenames_2(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
   struct appender{  
     std::string operator()(std::string const& s, FileInfo const& f)const 
      { return s + f.filename(); } 
   };

   return std::accumulate( std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), std::string(), appender() );
}

//Elapsed: 10729.381 microseconds
std::string sumof_filenames_3(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
      struct appender{
           std::string operator()(std::string & s, FileInfo const& f) const
           { return s+= f.filename(); }
      };
      std::accumulate( std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), std::string(), appender() );
}
```

**Q: How optimize sum_of_filenames using STL algorithms, such std::accumulate, or any others, and  how to implement appender functor ?**

test: main function :

```
int main()
   {
enum{ N = 1000* 1 };
srand(14324);
std::vector<FileInfo> fv;
fv.reserve(N);
for(std::size_t ix = 0; ix < N; ++ix)
{
    FileInfo f;
    f.m_Filename.resize(  static_cast< int > ( rand() *  256 / 32768 ) + 15 , 'A');
    //for( std::size_t iy = 0; iy < f.m_Filename.size(); ++iy)
    //  f.m_Filename[iy] = static_cast<char>( rand() * 100 / 32768 + 28 );

    fv.push_back( f );
}

LARGE_INTEGER freq, start, stop;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);

{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    std::string s = sumof_filenames_1(fv); 


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    double elapsed = (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)* 1000.0 / (double)(freq.QuadPart) * 1000.0;
    printf("Elapsed: %.3lf microseconds\n", elapsed);



    printf("%u\n", s.size());
}


{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    std::string s = sumof_filenames_2(fv); 


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    double elapsed = (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)* 1000.0 / (double)(freq.QuadPart) * 1000.0;
    printf("Elapsed: %.3lf microseconds\n", elapsed);



    printf("%u\n", s.size());
}




{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    std::string s = sumof_filenames_3(fv); 


    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    double elapsed = (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)* 1000.0 / (double)(freq.QuadPart) * 1000.0;
    printf("Elapsed: %.3lf microseconds\n", elapsed);



    printf("%u\n", s.size());
}
```

Comment: Is this a question out of general interest or do you ask, because you have exactly this problem? Because, if a simple one-liner is faster and shorter than the version with the std algorithm I don't seee the point in using it, even if there are faster solutions (as long as they are not faster than the naive solution of course).

Comment: In fact, you could even shorten it to `for (const auto& f: fv) s += f.filename();`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18703743/1639256).

Comment: FYI:  Unless I'm missing something, it looks like your times are being reported it milliseconds, not microseconds.  (You're reporting to microsecond precision, but the unit is milliseconds.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to estimate the following function

```
std::string sumof_filenames_3(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
      struct appender{
           std::string & operator()(std::string & s, FileInfo const& f) const
           { return s+= f.filename(); }
      };

      return std::accumulate( std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), std::string(), appender() );
}
```

and with using a lambda expression

```
std::string sumof_filenames_3(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
      return std::accumulate( std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), std::string(),
                              []( std::string &s, FileInfo const& f ) -> std::string &
                              {
                                 return s += f.filename();
                              } ); 
}
```

Also estimate the following loop

```
std::string sumof_filenames_1(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
   std::string::size_type n = 0;
   for each ( FileInfo const& f in fv ) n +=  f.filename().size();

   std::string s;
   s.reserve( n );

   for( std::size_t ix = 0u; ix < fv.size(); ++ix) s += fv[ix].filename();       

   return s;
}
```

Also do the same estimations for the structure defined the following way

```
struct FileInfo
{
   std::string filename_;
   const std::string & filename()const { return filename_;}
};
```

Comment: The `accumulate` function does `init = BinaryOperator(init, *first);`, so I think it is better to use `+` rather than `+=` in your operator.

Comment: @Matt McNabb If you will use operator + then the compiler will create a temporary object while if you will use operator += neither temporary object wilol be created.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Also you edited my post incorrectly. Using for each is not a typo. MS VC++ 2010 does not support the standard range based for statement.

Comment: How thoughtful of MS to make up their own syntax instead of checking what was about to be published as standard.

Comment: @Matt McNabb I think that this syntax appeared due to introducing the managed C++ known as C++/CLI that to make it similar to the foreach statement in C#

Comment: Temporary objects may be elided, and RVO can occur. I'm not even sure if the `+=` version is valid; the effect would be `init.operator=( BinaryOperator(init, *first);` , and evaluating `init` isn't sequenced-after the call to BinaryOperator. And you will end up doing a self-assignment in any case, since you return a reference to init.

Comment: @Matt McNabb The self-assignment is a good thing in this case because nothing will be done. It is what I want that the code would be more effective.

Comment: I would bet the "two loops, `reserve` first" would be the fastest answer. The multiple reallocations and copies of string buffers are the most probable cause of slowdowns in this example.

Answer (score 2):

A `for_each` comes to my mind like this:

```
std::string sumof_filenames(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
    std::string s;
    std::for_each(std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), [&s](const FileInfo& f){s += f.filename();});
    return s;
}
```

or without the lamba

```
struct Appender
{
    std::string& m_s;
    Appender(std::string& s):m_s(s){};
    void operator()(const FileInfo& f) const 
        { s += f.filename(); } 
};
std::string sumof_filenames(std::vector<FileInfo> const& fv )
{
    std::string s;
    std::for_each(std::begin(fv), std::end(fv), Appender(s)});
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `void operator()(const FileInfo f) const` take its argument by *reference*?

Comment: @Ali: Yes they definitely should. I changed my post