# C++ convert vector<std::string> to char*

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello as the title suggests I want to convert a vector,

```
 std::vector<std::string>
```

to a c-style string, like

```
char* buffer.
```

The reason I want the vector to become a c-style string is because I am currently working with the WinApi, and I am specifically trying to use

```
SetWindowTextA()
```

which does not take a vector.
And yes, I have to read the data in to a string vector first so there's not really anything I can change there. So if you could help me or point me in the right direction I'd be more than happy

EDIT:
To further explain:
Yes I will get several string loaded in to the vector. I simply want all those strings to combine in to one string.

Greetings,
ye546

Comment: Can you give an example how should the strings be combined into one?

Comment: `char*` is a single string, but you have several strings. You do want to insert `\n` between them?

Comment: Is l it should be easy to Google how to join a vector of string to a single string. And then just call .data().

Comment: `std::stringstream ss; auto sep = ""; for (auto&& s : v) { ss << sep << s; sep = " "; } SetWindowTextA(hwnd, ss.str().c_str());`

Comment: Can you use `.c_str()`?

Comment: How should the strings be combined?

Comment: Why don't you access your vector by index and use `.c_str()`? i.e: `SetWindowTextA(myVec[0].c_str())`. Do you understand that a vector of std::string has many strings in it?

Comment: It often helps to divide problems into smaller pieces. In this case, you've come very close to doing that, but you are still looking at this as one problem. Your goal consists of [Combining a vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985978/combining-a-vector-of-strings) followed by converting [std::string to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char), does it not?

Answer (score 0):

So just combine the vector strings into a single string, then call c_str() to convert to a char*.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
...
std::string combined;
for (const auto& s : vec)
    combined += s;
WinAPI(combined.c_str());
```

Comment: `std::string::c_str` returns `const char *`. Use `&combined[0]` instead.

Comment: `SetWindowTextA` takes a `char const*`, so using [c_str()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is perfectly fine.